# Exporting text to file with latest text as first line in the text file - C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to export a string to a text file with a timestamp. I am using File.AppendAllText("C:\list.txt", text); to make the text file. The prob with this is that - the first run will save the text and any subsequent runs will place the text below the first run text. I want it the other way round like latest text to be on the top as I want the latest timestamp to sit on the top.

thanks
Sri

Answer (score 1):

Adding text to the beginning of a file is a very expensive operation. Basically you need to read the entire file, and write it back with the added text, so it will be slower and slower the larger the file gets.

If you want to show the latest item first, then do that reversal when you display the file instead.

Comment: Yup, I don't think that's a viable option

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the existing file first and then append that text to your current message. Then you can overwrite the whole file with the new log.

Be careful though, this will be more work once the file increases in size.

Answer (score 0):

```
Void Method()
{
 string text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\text.txt");

 string  NewText="This is new Text " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

 File.WriteAllText(@"c:\text.txt", NewText + Environment.NewLine  + text);

}
```

Comment: thanks mazhar but I already record the timestamp,, need to know how to put latest timestamp as first line in the text file,,